# mysql database insert is changing all IDs to 4294967295

Tags: php, mysql, database

Something really weird is going on with my database. I am using PHP to insert data into my database and I have been doing this for the past 2 years without any problems. When a customer makes a payment on my website, I store all of the data from that transaction in my database. Each transaction has a unique "transaction_id". When I insert the payment information into the database, all of the information is correctly inserted except for the "transaction_id". ALL transactions are given the "transaction_id" of "4294967295".  So I did some testing. Here is what I did:

1) I echoed out the "transaction_id" to my screen to see what is would say. The results were that the "transaction_id" that was being echoed out was CORRECT. It was not the repeating "4294967295". However, when I look in my database, it shows "4294967295".

2) This time I decided to echo out the query to my web browser. The query was CORRECT. In the query, the CORRECT "transaction_id" was in the query. However, when I look in my database, it shows "4294967295".

I have 3 different pages where customers can make payments. ALL 3 pages started doing this on April 6th, 2012. None of those pages were modified at all. I have not modified those pages in over 2 years. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
$query = "INSERT INTO payments (customer_id, transaction_id, invoice_number, authorization_code, subscription, subscription_id, avs_result, cvv_result, amount, full_tuition, payment_date, ip_address) VALUES ({$_SESSION['customer_id']}, {$_SESSION['transaction_id']}, {$_SESSION['invoice_number']}, '{$_SESSION['authorization_code']}', '{$_SESSION['subscription']}', {$_SESSION['subscription_id']}, '{$_SESSION['avs_result']}', '{$_SESSION['cvv_result']}', {$_SESSION['amount']}, {$_SESSION['full_tuition']}, '{$_SESSION['payment_date']}', '{$_SESSION['ip_address']}')" ;
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) OR die ('<p>There was an error with the INSERT payments query.: ' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br />Query:' . $query . '</p>') ;

echo '<p>Transaction ' .  $_SESSION['transaction_id'] . ' has been <font color="green">APPROVED</font> by the system.</p>' ;

echo '<br /><br />' ;

echo '<p>Below is a summary:</p>' ;
echo '<p>Transaction ID: ' .  $_SESSION['transaction_id'] . '<br />
Payment Method: XXXX<br />
Amount: $' . $amount . '<br />
Customer Name: ' . $_SESSION['first_name'] . ' ' . $_SESSION['last_name'] . '<br />
</p>' ;

echo "<p>Note: Please do NOT click the browser's Back button to enter a new transaction.</p>" ;


echo $query ;
```

Comment: just to clerify the functionality I would suggest you to script the database without any data,triggers,... Make a new database with that script connect your site to the new db just to see if it is some sort of hack.

Cos at first glance it looks like a hack. Make sure you don't have any triggers or such on the database.

Comment: For the love of all things with apostrophes in them, spend thirty minutes and read the [PHP PDO Tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). Slinging arbitrary data into a SQL query is reckless.

Comment: Your real problem now is to find and fix the bad transactions. If you have related tables, you may have to contact the customer directly to find out what payments go to what.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your number is larger than the field in the DB can handle...

4294967295 is the largest number 32 bits can hold, your transaction ID is now larger than the numerical field your DB can hold.

Comment: @three3 give yourself a pat on the back for maxing it out

Answer (score 5):

Excellent job investigating the problem and reporting the results in your question!

4294967295 is the largest INT that mysql can hold, so transaction IDs higher than that are getting stored as 4294967295. To fix this, you can change the column type to BIGINT: `modify column transaction_id bigint`

This SHOULD convert the column type while preserving all your data, but it would be good to back up the database first just in case!

Answer (score 2):

4294967295 is conveniently 2^32-1 -- the maximum value for a 32 bit unsigned integer.  It looks like whatever transaction_id you're giving it is too big, so it's overflowing and MySQL's behaviour in that situation is to set it to the max.

Also, if you're using MySQLi, you should consider using prepared statements.  I'm not sure what the value of your session variables are, but I suspect they are unescaped so they either need to be escaped or use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Change the data type of the `transaction_id` to `BIGINT`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to look at your **auto increment value** of the table. In my case it was 4294967295 :/

Answer (score 0):

Me also faced the same issue , our client called asked about this , i test run the code and the solution is i changed the feild to varchar(100)
thank you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).